# Can lambda functions decay to a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, lambda, pointer-to-member, member-functions

In my understanding, lambdas are supposed to behave similarly to functions and even extend their functionality.

Because of this, captureless lambdas can decay to function pointers:

```
auto x = +[] (int x) {return x + 5;} // + triggers conversion to function pointer.
```

However, I have not found a way to make a lambda function behave similarly to a member function.

For example, the following snippet does not work:

```
class MyClass() {
   int x;
   static constexpr auto member_lambda_func = [this] () {return x + 5;}; //Does not compile. Cannot capture this.
};
```

Furthermore, you can't even make a lambda which captures `this` decay into a pointer to member function.

Is there a work around for making lambda member functions?
Or is there a good reason not to?

Comment: I would inverse the question - why would you want to?

Comment: @Fureeish Says you want to store a pointer to member function. And you want your API to be able to accept lambdas.

Comment: If that had worked, which `this` should the `static` member variable capture? The first?

Comment: First lambda is a function, second one is something more complex since it holds a state (`this`). Also `this` symbol is not available in this scope. As Ted point out what is should refer to?

Comment: @Marek R Like a member function when you use it inside the class.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623 this may give you some more insights on lambdas.

Comment: For me this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: "static" and "this" has a bit of oil and water... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas can decay to function pointers if they are captureless but they cannot decay to anything if they capture something. In particular, if it captures only `this` it cannot decay to member function pointer.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: So I can't make a lambda which behaves like a member function?

Comment: @Cyrus That depends what you mean. Calling a lambda that captures and operates on a certain instance can behave as a member-function of that instance, but you would still call it as if it was a free function.

Comment: @super But you can't store it in a class without resorting to the overhead of std::function

Comment: @Cyrus Not strictly correct, but close enough. A lambda has a unique unnamed type, so you can't store different lambdas in the same variable without resorting to type-erasure (`std::function` for example).

Comment: @super Exactly. That's why I wanted to make lambdas capturing this decay into pointer to member function but apparently it's not possible...

Comment: @Cyrus Your question could probably use some clarification. Instead of asking if it's possible to convert a lambda to a pointer-to-member-function you should ask about the problem that you think you would solve by doing that. Depending on your use case there might be a good way to do it, but without some more details to the question it's not really possible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

> Can lambda functions decay to a pointer to member function?

Short answer: No.

Lambdas can only convert to function pointers. And member function pointers are not function pointers (they aren't even pointers).

Furthermore only non-capturing lambdas an convert to function pointers. A lambda that captures `this` is a capturing lambda.

Something like this may be of use - I don't know for what purpose, but it is closest that I can think of to what you are asking for:

```
static constexpr auto member_lambda_func = [](const MyClass& self) {
    return self.x + 5;
};
```